# Hard coded GET values not sent from form

Tags: php, html, forms, web, get

In the action attribute of my form element I have specified some get values, which will be sent along with the value from the actual form. However the values I have hardcoded in are not sent to the new document, what am I doing wrong?

```
 <form action="loginForm.php?type=dept" method="get">
    <select name="dept" onchange="this.form.submit()">
      <option value="">Department</option>
      <option value="Bar">Bar</option>
      <option value="Cleaning">Cleaning</option>
      <option value="Kitchen">Kitchen</option>
      <option value="Management">Management</option>
      <option value="Maintenance">Maintenance</option>
      <option value="Waiting">Waiting</option>
    </select>
  </form>
```

At the top of the loginForm file is this code, which will output 'Type not set' every time

```
if(!isset($_GET['type']))
{
    echo 'Type not set';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the get parameters you are "forcing" by putting them in the URL are "overwritten" when the page is submitted. You will need to use a hidden field like:

```
input type="hidden" name="type" value="valuehere" />
```

Adding this to your form will submit this additional value.

Answer (score 0):

Try to send it using `hidden` input like this :     `<input type='hidden' name='type' value='dept' />`

Your code should be like this :

```
<form action="loginForm.php" method="get">
    <input type='hidden' name='type' value='dept' />
    <select name="dept" onchange="this.form.submit()">
      <option value="">Department</option>
      <option value="Bar">Bar</option>
      <option value="Cleaning">Cleaning</option>
      <option value="Kitchen">Kitchen</option>
      <option value="Management">Management</option>
      <option value="Maintenance">Maintenance</option>
      <option value="Waiting">Waiting</option>
    </select>
  </form>
```